# Datagrip, create custom template

Tags: sql, templates, datagrip

I was wondering if it is possible to create my custom SQL template in Datagrip.
 As users of Datagrip know, if you type `sel` and then wait or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, a panel is shown with options. One of them is the template for:

```
Select * from ;
```

How could I create my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out that if you type in a new file, for example:

```
sel and then hit CTRL+space
```

it will show:

[image]

Click the yellow lamp in the right top corner of the popup. It will show another menu with **"Edit live template settings"** option inside it where you can create your own templates.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings → Editor → Live Templates

[image: Live templates settings]

Also, follow [official custom live template creation guidance](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/using-live-templates.html).